# Meaning of "foregrounding"

Tags: meaning

> The EU should stop talking about **foregrounding** conditionality.

What does *foregrounding* mean here? Is it a gerund or an adjective?

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about forms of _foreground_? Also, please provide more context.

Comment: my dictionary says that foreground can be a (n) or a (v) and list possible meanings but I'm not sure if any can fit the context.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Also include your dictionary definitions along with why you think they don't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bringing it to the front of a discussion, discourse or description.

*Conditionality* is a concept that comes up a lot in discussion of the various arrangements to assist EU countries that are in debt.*

To foreground it, would be to keep bringing it to the front of any planning about the bail-outs, loans and other such measures.

Yes, it's a gerund.

**Conditionality* itself in such discussions is a word that conveys two concepts; 1. "Conditions", 2. "I am on television or the radio, so I will stick *-ality* onto a noun to make another noun because more-syllables means more-smarts and hopefully voters will think I'm smart next election time".

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to ask again "**stop talking about** foregrounding conditionality" means that they should stop emphasising it? Or stop bringing it up in their meetings? I mean **stop talking** literally or figuratively?

Comment: They want it to be emphasised within any agreements reached, so they are talking about emphasising it. This person thinks they should stop such talk. (I also think they should stop talking about it, if only because "conditionality" as a word is a pet peeve of mine).